# Position 3 span elements inside a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position 3 span elements inside a div. I have this code:

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
}
#one {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 5%;
}
#two {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 40%;
}
#three {
  position: relative;
  left: 70%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div><span id="one">left</span><span id="two">middle</span><span id="three">right</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that when you change the words left, middle and right, the positioning shifts, so they're no longer centred. How do I centre these span elements regardless of the text content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
}
.inner {
   width: 33%;
   float: left;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div><span id="one" class="inner">right</span><span id="two" class="inner">middle</span><span id="three" class="inner">left</span>
</div>
```

If you want to cover the 1% of width (3 x 33% = 99%) you can do this:

```
.inner {
    float: left;
    text-align: center
}
.inner:not(:nth-of-type(2)) {
    width: 33%;
}
.inner:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 34%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand. Tell me if this helps you.

```
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
}

div span {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hy2o7nh1/

You can change the spans width as you wish... or add `text-align:center;`... remove the border... ect'